# PHP - File created with a line break at the beginning

Tags: php, file, text, line, break

I need to create a text file to download on the fly, but i just can't get rid of a line break at the beginning of the file, i tried a lot of trim, replaces but the first line still there, i need this file to be created without line breaks at the beginning since it will be used by another application that does not expect a line break at the beginning.

Here's the code:

```
$strfilename = "test.txt";
$testFile = fopen($strfilename, "w") or die("Error!");

//header
$strLine = "test|1\r\n";
$strLine .= "A|1|2|\r\n";
$line_out = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $strLine);
$line_out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $strLine);
fwrite($testFile, $line_out);

fclose($testFile);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($strfilename));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($testFile));
readfile($strfilename);
exit;
```

When opening the file using notepad, for example, the first line isnt there:

```
1 - test|1
2 - A|1|2|
```

But if you open it using an advanced text editor (Notepad++ for example) you can see a line break at the beginning:

```
1 - 
2 - test|1
3 - A|1|2|
```

Comment: This could be resulted in by different charsets or encoding method used by different editors.

Comment: `$line_out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $strLine);` is a problem... you're doing the `preg_replace()` of `$strLine` to `$line_out`; then overwriting it with the result of the `str_replace()` of `$strLine`

Comment: @ildflue how do i set a proper encoding when creating a txt file on the fly?

Comment: Learn how to use PHP's fputcsv() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

```
$strfilename = "test.txt";
$testFile = '';

//header
$strLine = "test|1\r\n";
$strLine .= "A|1|2|\r\n";
$line_out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $strLine);
$testFile .= $line_out;

file_put_contents(trim($strfilename));

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($strfilename));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($testFile));
readfile($strfilename);
exit;
```

to break it down

`$testFile = file_get_contents($strfilename);` gets all the file contents to string, this can be omitted and using `$testFile = '';` is perfectly enough for the rest of the code - **if the file is empty.**

`$testFile .= $line_out;` puts your text into $testFile variable

`file_put_contents(trim($strfilename));` this writes down the file, with all line breaks at the beginning or end, cleaned up.

`$line_out = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '', $strLine);` is removed as it is unnecessary

---

In your own code, your file `$strfilename` already has a line break in it , and when you fopen it, you get the file, without changing what it has, hence the linebreak at the beginning. And you fwrite a bit and fclose the file, without removing the first line break. It **won't** make any difference if you trim `$line_out` as the line break is in the file.

Comment: Still breaking the first line.
The line breaks are gone for the entire string, which is not a problem.

Could it be related to the php version on the server?

Comment: can you do `$testFile = '';` instead of `$testFile = file_get_contents($strfilename);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

$strfilename = "test.txt";
$testFile = fopen($strfilename, "w") or die("Error!");

//header
$strLine = "test|1\r\n";
$strLine .= "A|1|2|\r\n";
$line_out = preg_replace('/[\r]+/', '', $strLine);
$line_out = str_replace(array("\r"), "", $strLine);
$line_out = trim($line_out);
fwrite($testFile, $line_out);
fclose($testFile);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($strfilename));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($strfilename));

readfile($strfilename);
exit;
```

Comment: Tried trim already and still now working... thanks for your help!